# Skip decimal points on y-axis in chartJS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using [this](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) library to draw charts in my web app. The issue is that I am having decimal points in my y-axis. You can see that in the image below [image]

Is there a way that I can restrict it to only have numbers?

This is my code

```
var matches = $("#matches").get(0).getContext("2d");

var data = {
        labels: labelsFromCurrentDateTillLastWeek,
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "Last Weeks Matches",
                fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data: result
            }
        ]
    };

    var options = {
        scaleLabel: function (label) {
            return Math.round(label.value);
        }
    };

    var myLineChart = new Chart(matches, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: data,
        options: options

    })
```

Answer (score 148, accepted):

**Update:** please see an updated answer from `@DreamTeK` that shows how this can now be done as part of the chartjs api https://stackoverflow.com/a/54006487/2737978

---

in chartjs 2.x you can pass an option for a `userCallback` to the yaxis tick field. In this you can check if the label is a whole number

here is an example

```
 options = {
     scales: {
         yAxes: [{
             ticks: {
                 beginAtZero: true,
                 userCallback: function(label, index, labels) {
                     // when the floored value is the same as the value we have a whole number
                     if (Math.floor(label) === label) {
                         return label;
                     }

                 },
             }
         }],
     },
 }
```

[fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/1vy6hdjk/)

Comment: Is there a COMPLETE document guide for these charts? This http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html is detailed but says nothing about beginAtZero for example.

Comment: The best solution. No bug, no problem

Comment: Easier option: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/radial/linear.html?h=stepsize#tick-options

Comment: @Chris the issue with that is all your charts will then use that `stepSize`. this is fine if you know you are always displaying data between 1 and 5 but if you are displaying data between 1 and 1000 it will still use the same step size

Comment: This should be a simple flag. IMHO this is a very general use case and should be implemented like that.

Answer (score 109):

## 2019 Update

This can now easily be achieved using the `precision` option:

```
ticks: {
  precision:0
}
```

As per the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/radial/linear.html?h=precision#tick-configuration).

> If defined and stepSize is not specified, the step size will be rounded to this many decimal places.

**EXAMPLE**

```
options: {
  scale: {
    ticks: {
      precision: 0
    }
  }
}
```

**OR** *(Single Axis)*

```
options: {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        precision: 0
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: For others, note that this property doesn't seem to affect the labels when the user hovers/taps on a point in the graph...

Comment: Where should you put `ticks`?

Comment: @tonix It's in options/scale/ticks. There's a link to the official documentation and example in my post.

Comment: Does not seem to work in version 3 any more

Comment: Not working for [chartjs-plugin-zoom 1.2.0](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-zoom/latest/guide/usage.html) and chart.js 3.7.0 when zooming.

Answer (score 33):

**Update**: replaced references to 'fixedStepSize' with 'stepSize'.

Another alternative is to use the stepSize option as follows:

```
options = {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                stepSize: 1
            }
        }],
    },
};
```

Comment: This *should* be that simple. Unfortunately, this setting prevents skipping certain points when there is a lot of data. For example, when the values are from 0 to 1000, chart.js will display all integers from 0 to 1000 instead of displaying e.g. 0, 100, 200 etc.

Comment: Good to know. So in essence, it works where the range of values is limited to what can be displayed reasonably within the available space.

Comment: Currently using 2.7 and 'fixedStepSize' should be 'stepSize' see docs: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/radial/linear.html?h=stepsize#tick-options. Also does not play well if applying currency formatting.

Answer (score 23):

You can adding stepSize and beginAtZero option like this:

```
scales: {
  yAxes: [{
    ticks: {
      stepSize: 1,
      beginAtZero: true,
    },
  }],
},
```

Comment: For Chart.js 2.9.4, `stepSize` works. thanks!!

Comment: Please do not use the words "latest version" on this site.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest and most straight forward solution is to add these configurations to your options object:

```
    scales: {
  yAxes: [
    {
      ticks: {
        precision: 0,
        beginAtZero: true,
      },
    },
  ],
},
```

and define the Axes (In my case it is the yAxes) depending on your axes with fractions

Answer (score 4):

if you are using chart.js version **3.9.1** or higher , **yAxes** and **xAxes** will not work,
also you may get this error in your console

> Invalid scale configuration for scale: yAxes

for solving this problem you should use **y** instead of **yAxes** and **x** instead of **xAxes** .

example:

```
scales: {
        y: {
          suggestedMin: 0,
          ticks: {
            precision: 0
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

I use this:

```
yAxes: [
        {
            ticks: {
                    callback: function(val) {
                    return Number.isInteger(val) ? val : null;
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

*Note*: use the callback function for better granular control. We check if val is an integer instead of a floating-point decimal. If it is, we return the value. If not, we return null.

Answer (score 2):

## Chart.js v3 (2022+)

The most reliable way with Chart.js v3 is not to use `ticks.precision`, but instead provide your own formatter with **`ticks.callback`**.

Example on how to format y axis labels:

```js
scales: {
  y: {
    ticks: {
      callback: (yValue) => {
        return Math.floor(yValue); // format to your liking
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Documentation: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/scale-options/ticks.html

Answer (score 1):

You can yaxis optopn;

decimalsInFloat: Number

Number of fractions to display when there are floating values in y-axis.
Note: If you have defined a custom formatter function in yaxis.labels.formatter, this won’t have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

if your chartjs version above 2.8
you can easily use precision: 0

study the below example

````
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      title: {
        display: true,
        position: 'top',
        text: 'Monthly Establish Documents Value',
        fontSize: 25
      },
      scales: {
        xAxes: [
          {
            stacked: true,
            scaleLabel: {
              display: true,
              labelString: 'Months'
            }
          }
        ],

        yAxes: [
          {
            stacked: true,
            beginAtZero: true,
            id: 'A',
            scaleLabel: {
              display: true,
              labelString: '$AUD'
            }
          },
          {
            stacked: false,
            beginAtZero: true,
            id: 'B',
            gridLines: {
              display: false
            },
            scaleLabel: {
              display: true,
              labelString: '#Clients '
            },
            position: 'right',
            ticks: {
              min: 0,
              precision: 0
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    } ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with all the examples above. Ended up having to use a callback. I'm using this in Typescript ReactJS FYI.cardSettings.precision contains the precision. This is a snippet from my code

```
 const [chartOptions, setChartOptions] = useState<ChartOptions<'line'>>({
    responsive: true,
    plugins: { 
    },
    scales: { 
        y: {
            display: true,
            ticks: {
                callback: function (value, index, values) { 
                    return parseFloat(value.toString()).toFixed(cardSettings.precision);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```